# Jssor MinDragOffsetToSlide option working only for sliding right to left

Tags: jssor

It seems that the option $MinDragOffsetToSlide is working only in one direction (when sliding back, right to left).
Tested with the demos. Is it an expected behavior? How to apply it to sliding in both directions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug has been fixed and uploaded. Please download from https://github.com/jssor/slider